# Dotted style overlay effect

Tags: html, css

I have recently stumbled uppon this website [GrandPixels](http://demo.grandpixels.com/?theme=linguini)
and found one interesting effect. In the slideshow section you can see that images are kind of dotted, by zooming in I discovered that these dots are not the parts of the images but sort of overlay, achieved with CSS, I assume. Could anyone explain how this effect is achieved, ideally with css?

Comment: You could use FireBug Tool from Mozilla to see exactly the css from a certain part!

Comment: Event IE has got developement tools or chrome.

Comment: That is one of the greatest Wordpress themes I've ever seen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's done with 2x2 overlay transparent PNG image that can be extracted from here: 
[Background Overlay Pattern](http://grandpixels.com/linguini/wp-content/themes/linguini1.5/images/bg-overlay-pattern.png)

Afterwards the class `slideshow-overlay` applied to an element to make it work:

```
.slideshow-overlay {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -99;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url("images/bg-overlay-pattern.png") left top repeat
}
```

Answer (score 1):

They are using a 2x2 px image in a div as a background to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

The css class is called `.slideshow-overlay` and it uses an dotted image `images/bg-overlay-pattern.png`(2x2) that is `background-repeated` over the image with `posititon:fixed`. If you use firebug like I told you in the comment, you will see exactly the **css** used!

Answer (score 0):

It's div with [image](http://grandpixels.com/linguini/wp-content/themes/linguini1.5/images/bg-overlay-pattern.png), which overlay slides image.
If you want to do something like that you need to add div before you slides with this css:

```
display: block;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: -99;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background: url('../images/bg-overlay-pattern.png') left top repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
.slides .img
{
     background: url(images/slide1.png) no-repeat;
}

.slides .img:after {
                content: "";
                background: url(images/pattern.png) repeat scroll left top transparent;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                right: 0;
                position: absolute;
                z-index: -1;
            }
```